# Facebook FQL : link-type post's location tag data is missing

Tags: facebook-fql

I've posted a link-type post with a location tag on Facebook Web. Now I'm trying to get that post with it's location tag via FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, type, place FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0
```

The post is successfully retrieved, but with place = null. In "link" table there's no way to get place data. Where can I get link-type posts location tag data?

Comment: That's a Facebook bug. reported here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/478567888825332?browse=search_5036b94d0e62d2437772284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in FB, present for at least 6 months already. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/478567888825332?browse=search_5036b94d0e62d2437772284